# Best way to avoid preparing the same PDO statement more than once?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

Currently I save prepared statements into a private variable, because I ignore how they really work in the deepness, and do it just in case.

So the question is really simple, if I iterate over the same `$PDO->prepare()`, will it prepare again the same query?

```
foreach( $arr as $docid ) {
  if( $this->dbLink === null ) { // PDO resource, saved in the object.
     throw new Exception( 'Must first connect to DB' );
  }
  if( $this->queryCheckAccess === null ) {
    $query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
    $this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
  }
  else {
    $result = $this->queryCheckAccess->execute(array(':id'=>$docid));
  }
}
```

Will it matter ? Or the DB Engine / PHP is smart enough to know that it is the same prepared statement?

Thanks a lot.

**----------------- EDIT --------------**

I think I was misunderstood.

What I ask is what happens if I do:

```
$query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
$this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
$query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
$this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
$query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
$this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
$query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
$this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
```

And what happens if I do:

```
if( $this->queryCheckAccess === null ) {
  $query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
  $this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
}
```

Will the engine prepare the query 4 times in the first example? Or will notice it is the same query and just "jump" that?

Comment: If you're looping over the same query and only changing the values you should prepare once and bind several times. This way, you tell MySQL about the query once, and only pass in different values for each subsequent query. I don't think you'll run into any bugs because you're preparing over and over but you might notice some slowness.

Comment: Why are you preparing the same query over and over?

Comment: @silkfire To see if it is needed to save it to a object property in order to avoid that, prepare the same query over and over and over.

Comment: @Jorge Doesn't really make sense. Prepare a query once and that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just RUN a code similar to your example, and enabled [MySQL Query LOG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) I found that all prepare requests are sent to MySQL Server

```
   Prepare  SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username = ?
   Close stmt   
   Prepare  SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username = ?
   Close stmt   
   Prepare  SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username = ?
   Close stmt   
   Prepare  SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username = ?
   Close stmt
```

Test code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(1, $user);
$sth->execute();
```

Then, the best way is to prepare once, and Bind different values and then execute.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$user = "test";
$sth->bindParam(1, $user);
$sth->execute();

$user = "test2";
$sth->bindParam(1, $user);
$sth->execute();

$user = "test";
$sth->bindParam(1, $user);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code only prepares the query once, because after the first loop iteration, it's not NULL so it the conditional block won't run. But it's a waste of time to check the condition every time through the loop.

But to answer your question, if you prepare() the same query, it does do redundant work, even if the query is identical to the one you prepared before. So you should avoid that.

But you don't need to prepare inside the loop at all. Prepare once before you start the loop, and bind a variable to the parameter. You don't need to bind every time in the loop, just change the value of that variable.

```
if( $this->dbLink === null ) { // PDO resource, saved in the object.
    throw new Exception( 'Must first connect to DB' );
}
$query = 'SELECT * from something where id = :id';
$this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
$this->queryCheckAccess->bindParam(':id' => $docidparam);
foreach( $arr as $docid ) {
    $docidparam = $docid;
    $result = $this->queryCheckAccess->execute();
}
```

I'm not sure if you can bind the variable and also use it as the loop variable, there might be a scope conflict.

Another suggestion for this query:  why not just run one query to search for a list of values?

```
$list = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($arr), "?"));
$query = "SELECT * FROM something WHERE id IN ( $list )";
$this->queryCheckAccess = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
$this->queryCheckAccess->execute($arr);
```

PS: Also you should check for errors. If you enable PDO error mode EXCEPTION, then errors will automatically throw exceptions. If you don't enable that mode, you need to check the return value of prepare() and execute(), which return **false** if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks, the bad thing is that checkAccess is called from another function in a foreach loop, so I cannot prepare() outside the checkAccess function because it is its task.

Comment: Can you please see my answer and outline any difference between my test code and OP's code? am I did wrong test?

Comment: @JasonOOO, the OP's code sets `$this->queryCheckAccess` to a PDOStatement resource in the first iteration of the loop.  So it's not NULL after that.  In all subsequent iterations, the `if()` condition evaluates as **false**, so the prepare doesn't happen.

Comment: @BillKarwin: I knew that, what about first case (see it under edit), OP sends same prepared query.

Comment: @JasonOOO, yes, absolutely prepare() does not skip the statement if it is the same as before.  It prepares the statement every time.  But we're now talking about two different approaches to the code, one which calls prepare() in a conditional block, and one which calls prepare() for each iteration.  Obviously these have different behavior.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's one of the main features of prepared statements. If you're going to run the same query multiple times but with different variables then preparing the query will give you a speed increase. Especially if you make use of transactions (requires InnoDB storage engine).

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers the question. Sure, prepared statements make it faster, but there's no need to prepare more than once. The OP's question is if the prepare is executed multiple times even if the statement is the same (so if he must avoid it or if it doesn't matter).

Answer (score -1):

- To answer the question from the title (which is quite different from questions in the body), the best way to avoid preparing the same statement more than once, apparently would be to **avoid running multiple similar queries** at all.
- To answer the question from the question body - no, DB Engine / PHP is not "smart" enough to know that it is the same query were prepared again. With every new prepare() call another statement is created. And I would be first to hate such a "smart" behavior. The "smarter" your tool, the more unpredictable results you get.
- To answer the *real* problem in the code, a smart developer would use a right tool to save himself a trouble.
  With [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) whole mess will be reduced to one query and one line of code

  ```
  $data = $this->dbLink->getAll('SELECT * from somth where id IN (?a)', $arr);
  ```

  S0 - no multiple queries, no multiple preparations, no multiple questions.

By the way, you are losing first id with your code. 
Yet you're losing all of them but last one if you don't use the result in place.

Comment: `So the question is really simple, if I iterate over the same $PDO->prepare(), will it prepare again the same query?` this is the questioned asked, you not answered it, OP asks if he prepare same query multiple times, if PHP prepare once or multiple times on same query?